# Accuracy issues in using booleans to evaluate expressions

Tags: optimization, cuda, kernel, boolean

I am trying to remove some if statements in my code in order to make it more suitable for use in a Cuda kernel. The if-else statements have the following format:

```
if(boolean 1) {
  double1 = expression1;
}
else if(boolean 2) {
  double1 = expression2;
}
else {
  double1 = expression3;
}
```

My attempt at removing the if statements looks something like this:

```
double1 = (boolean1) * expression1 + 
          (!boolean1 && boolean2) * expression2 +
          !(boolean1 && boolean2) * expression3;
```

The conversion to the no-if-statement form apparently works just fine, ie I get answers that are in the ballpark. However, there's slight differences. This is for a program that will iterate over the same kernels thousands of times in order to calculate displacements of material points. To test though I compared the if-statement & no-if-statement after only 50 time steps and this is the difference:

```
if statements:    -2.2900031243(9010440)e-004
no if statements: -2.2900031243(8959510)e-004
```

I've stepped through the code and evaluated the expressions separately and found that they match, only when combined with the boolean expressions is when I see the issue. I've tried casting the boolean expressions to doubles, but came out with the same answer. Does anyone have any idea if there's a way to solve this issue? My goal is speedup, so using the if statements is a last resort. Both numbers above are from two different CPU implementations I made to compare the code. This is not a difference between the GPU and CPU calculations. I appreciate any suggestions.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with these changes? If you are lucky the compiler recognizes the idiom and internally converts it back to it's old form. If not, you get inferior code.

Comment: I'm basically trying to replace the if-else block with one expression so I don't get divergent threads. I don't understand your comment about converting back to the old form, what old form?

Comment: If you want to do that, write `double1 = boolean1 ? expression1 : (boolean2 ? expression2 : expression3`. However when you look at the resulting code using `cuobjdump -sass`, you will probably find that the compiler generates exactly the same code as with the original conditional code. Don't underestimate modern optimizing compilers!

Comment: And `s/old/original/' in my original (first) comment.

Comment: Just wanted chime in with what @tera said -- even though you have removed the `if` statements, you still have conditional code. The compiler will look at how much conditional code there is and implement it either with branching or with [predication](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Branch_predication).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have mistranslated,

```
double1 = (boolean1) * expression1 + 
          (!boolean1 && boolean2) * expression2 +
          !(boolean1 && boolean2) * expression3;
```

adds `expression3` whenever either of `boolean1` and `boolean2` is false, but

```
if(boolean 1) {
  double1 = expression1;
}
else if(boolean 2) {
  double1 = expression2;
}
else {
  double1 = expression3;
}
```

uses `expression3` only if *both* of `boolean1` and `boolean2` are false.

The correct translation would use

```
+ !(boolean1 || boolean2) * expression3
```

Comment: What a head slapping moment. Thanks!

Comment: For educational purposes you can use `cuobjdump -sass` on your executable to look at the code the compiler generates from the corrected version of your replacement code. Compare that with your original code and my suggested replacement and you will likely change your view of the usefulness of the whole exercise.